# Why "playing stupid" sounds funny?

Tags: phrase-usage

> "Are you retarded, or just plain stupid?"

I am trying to paraphrase a sentence from the movie, "Forest Gump", to one of my American friends. But I misread the word 'plain', and I read it as 'playing'. So the sentence becomes "Are you retarded, or just **playing** stupid?"

This made my friend laugh a lot.

**Question:** Why does "*playing stupid*" sound so funny?

Comment: Just a general wonderment: Did you ask him why he thought it was so funny? Maybe he's laughing because this reminded him of a time something like this happened, in the past. I'm just assuming, though.

Comment: @VarunNair, I did, and he said 'playing stupid' sounds funny to him. He just couldn't explain it well. So, I might guess the verb 'play' doesn't work very well with stupid, and playing stupid as a whole oddly sounds funny, maybe?

Comment: Side question, did you mishear or misread?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I misread. A native person heard it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got from **plain** to **playing** if you were reading a transcript of the movie's dialogue. We cannot know what your friend found funny, but in some southern regional dialects of AmE, the diphthong in **plain** would sound nearly disyllabic, almost like **playin'**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, thanks, so I am wondering if "playing stupid" could make sense? If so, what would it mean?

Comment: Actually, 'playing stupid' seems apposite. There's none as thick as those that want to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an idiomatic expression *playing dumb* which means "to pretend to be dumb."  *Playing stupid* sounds like you're saying "pretending to be stupid."

Comment: Or if it could mean  "pretending to be stupid", the sentence I made by accident,  "Are you retarded, or just playing stupid?" indeed could make sense, right?